# Fundamental groupoid of $\Pi (S^1 \wedge S^1)$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

How do you show that the fundamental groupoid $\Pi(S^1 \vee S^1) \simeq \mathbb{Z} \star \mathbb{Z}$? I understand how to do so in the case of groups, but don't totally understand what's going on in the case of groupoids?

I feel I'm a bit confused about the difference between the fundamental group and groupoid. I suppose the answer that was deleted was confused as well...

Comment: Do you mean $\Pi(S^1\vee S^1)$? (The fundamental groupoid is $\Pi$, and $\vee$ is wedge product rather than smash product.)

Comment: @KyleMiller Oh yes didn't even notice the typo.

Comment: The fundamental groupoid of a path-connected space is (equivalent to) the groupoid $BG$ where $G$ is the fundamental group.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan What is $B$?

Comment: For the comparison between groups and groupoids,  see the discussion and references at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40945/compelling-evidence-that-two-basepoints-are-better-than-one  .

Comment: @Anthony: for $G$ a group, $BG$ is my preferred notation for the one-object groupoid with automorphisms $G$. Some people just call this groupoid $G$, which in my opinion is bad notation.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  There would then be  a conflict of notation as $BG$ is also used well for the classifying space of a group, or groupoid, $G$.

Comment: There's no real conflict there; groupoids embed fully faithfully into homotopy types as the homotopy 1-types, so under the honotopy hypothesis you're more or less still talking about the same object. (More concretely, groupoids embed fully faithfully into Kan complexes via taking the nerve.)